# deep link not working in my application

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am testing following deep link from email

http://smart-iptv.m3u

to open my app with activity as:

```
 <activity android:banner="@drawable/tv_banner" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="example.iptv.ChannelsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="ftp"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/x-mpegurl"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/xspf+xml"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="ftp"/>
                <data android:host="*"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u"/>                   
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.M3U"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m3u8"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xspf"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But all time the m3u file is being downloaded from browser.

Comment: Try to remove `<data android:host="*"/>` since I don't think host wildcards is permitted here.

Comment: try setting host to `http://smart-iptv.m3u`

Comment: still it not working after setting host as `<data android:host="smart-iptv"/>` on click browser opened